# Why is trace of rank-d projection matrix is d

Tags: linear-algebra

I have enrolled in an online machine learning course and I am new to Linear Algebra, I have this exercise problem to solve.

We are given $X ∈ R^{n×d}$ where n > d and rank(X) = d.

We are also given a vector y ∈ $R^{n}$.
Define the orthogonal projection of y onto range(X) as PX(y).

(a) An orthogonal projection is a linear transformation. Hence, we can define $P_{X}(y) = Py$ for some projection matrix P. Specifically, given 1 ≤ d ≤ n, a matrix $P ∈ R^{n×n}$ is said to be a rank-d orthogonal projection matrix if rank(P) = d, $P = P^{T}$ and $P^{2} = P$. Prove that P is a rank-d orthogonal projection matrix if and only if there exists a $U ∈ R^{n×d}$ such that $P=UU^{T}$
and $U^{T}U = I$.

(b) Prove that if P is a rank d projection matrix, then tr(P) = d.

As I do not have any help in this course can someone, please help me in solving this problem a and b part?

I tried to solve the (a) part but I am able to prove it mathematically but I do understand the idea that if P is of rank d, so it can be factorized into two matrices of rank-d each but I am not sure as to how to do it formally.

Thank you

Comment: Hint: The trace of a matrix is equal to the sum of its eigenvalues, taking multiplicity into account.

Comment: But why do the eigenvalues be 1, I get the idea that we will have d non-zero eigenvalues. Can you please explain further? Thanks

Comment: Think about what $P$ does to elements of the range of $X$, then relate that to the basic definition of eigenvectors and eigenvalues.

Comment: Since the matrix satisfies $P^{2} = P$ eigenvalues must satisfy the same equation, just apply both sides to an eigenvector. Hence they are $1$ or $0$.

Comment: Thank you very much, that solves the problem.